# How can I configure the time increment for the jump buttons in VLC's web control interface?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm running VLC on my laptop and controlling it via its web interface on my phone. There is a button in the UI that I can click to jump backwards by 30 seconds, which I've circled in red:

[image]

30 seconds is too long for what I'm doing; I want to be able to seek 10 seconds backwards. (I'm watching a foreign language show and frequently need to skip back to repeat the last sentence of dialog).

How can I configure the amount of time that this button skips by?

Answer (score 0):

The 30 second skip duration [is hard-coded into the file `mobile.html`](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/blob/b7b5fd49/share/lua/http/mobile.html#L67), which is the source file for the web remote control UI. So there is likely no setting to change it.

A work-around is to edit the file `mobile.html` and change the values `-30S` and `+30S` to e.g. `-10S` and `+10S`. I tried this and it worked. On my system (Arch Linux) the file `mobile.html` is located at `/usr/share/vlc/lua/http/mobile.html`, but it will vary depending on your OS.